# Images as Planes leaving white areas of images looking gray

Tags: add-on

Need some help here, guys.  Pretty new to Blender; I've created a scene (set in a rather gloomy looking tunnel) with warning signs attached to the walls.  The signs were added as images as planes; kept it as simple as possible.  But any part of the images that are supposed to be white look a nasty gray.  Help!

Edit: I've added an image of the light node set-up.  Thanks!

Edit #2: May have inadvertently solved this one myself!  Playing with the ambient occlusion settings is allowing me to bring out the white of the images!  Now to just get the settings right so my tunnel scene doesn't look too bright!

[![Material nodes][1]][1]

[image: The Scene]

[image: Light set-up]

Comment: If the renders are being done in Blender's internal system, then it's likely you will need to up the shading settings.  That's found under the "Material" properties at right. (little ball icon), open it's "shading" tab, either tick the "Shadeless" box, or slide the "Emit" tab to whatever is required.  Additionally open the "Specular" and reduce that to zero.  There are other avenues for increasing brightness of texture but that would require delving into the "Influence" features in the Texturing properties. Try this for now...

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, this is in cycles.  Any ideas for that?

Comment: Never used cycles unfortunately, takes too long to produce video.  Lots of people do though and are bound to answer your question.  Good luck.

Comment: It would be easyer to help you if you show your material node tree.
Are the textures .png?

Comment: The images are jpegs... as far as the nodes (forgive me; I'm new on here and not sure how to add an image to this comment string), it's an image texture hooked into a diffuse shader and then straight in to the material output.

Comment: Just double-checked... the images are a mix of jpegs and pngs.

Comment: Please post images of your material nodes, render settings, lights or other info matón that can help others understand your scene. Consider uploading your file as well

Comment: I was only able to add the one image: the lights.  As far as my material, it's an image texture hooked into a diffuse shader and then straight in to the material output.  Very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors are directly relative to light, your "white" value is determined by the color of the texture but by the light too (colors are just parts of light spectrum not absorbed).
For the diffuse part, RGB of 0.8 means that the surface diffuse 80% of the light it recieved.
For exemple pure red means (in RGB values) that green and blue are absorbed R=1 G=0 B=0.
Just to let you know there isn't any materials that returns 100% of the light it recieved.

3D rendering needs knowledge about light and photographie, I recommande you to read about this two topics.
There is a good doc about physically based rendering by [Allegorithmic](https://www.allegorithmic.com/pbr-guide) that you can read too.

Edit your question to add pictures if you can, I don't remember if you have the right when you start here.

Comment: I was able to add an image of my light set-up... unfortunately, as a newb on here, I guess I'm limited to just the two images.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know the purpose of the geometry node with dot product for your scene?
You don't need the light fall off, by default the strength fall off is already quadratic.
Do a test, in place of the diffuse shader of the texture put an emission shader, if the texture display like you want, it means that the light of your scene isn't suffisant to give you the "white" you want.
I couldn't be more helpfull.

Comment: Got it!  I'll test that, Mareck!  Thanks for the help!